# Flutter - How to change the rotation direction of a Container?

Tags: flutter, animation, rotation, transform

So I have a container that currently rotates along the Y axis as desired. The only thing is I am unable to changed its direction (anticlockwise to clockwise).

[image]

```
   Center(
                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _controller,
                    builder: (_, child) {
                      // RotationTransition(
                      //   turns: _animTurn,
                      //   child: Icon(
                      //     Icons.settings_sharp,
                      //     size: 100,
                      //   ),
                      //   alignment: Alignment.center,
                      // );
                      return Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                          ..rotateY(
                            _controller.value * (math.pi),
                          ),
                        // ..rotateZ(
                        //   math.pi *
                        //       2 *
                        //       _controller
                        //           .value, //change 0 to any value to rotate z Axis
                        // ),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 300,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),

                            boxShadow:

                                [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.8),
                                spreadRadius: 15,
                                blurRadius: 20,
                                offset: const Offset(-10, 0),
                              ),
   
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                                spreadRadius: 16,
                                blurRadius: 32,
                                offset: const Offset(-10, 0),
                              ),

                            ]
                            
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

As you can see in the commented code, I tried rotationTransition but it doesn't help, cause it rotates along the Z axis. e.g. https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-rotationtransition-widget-examples
This is not something that I am looking for.

Comment: Like a RotatedBox? flutter have RotatedBox

Comment: No, that's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the rotation by adding a minus(-) sign with pi value like this:

```
transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                          ..rotateY(
                            _controller.value * (-math.pi),
                          ),
```

[image]